# How to increase the SQS delay time to be more than 900 seconds

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs, jobs

I have a job command with a delay of 3600 seconds. so when the command fails, it'll run after 1 hour. But unfortunately this morning I have noticed SQS is not allowing this, and it responded with this error

```
Value 3600 for parameter DelaySeconds is invalid. Reason: DelaySeconds must be >= 0 and <= 900. -
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from delaying on producer or consumer side ?

Comment: The maximum delivery delay for an Amazon SQS queue has always been 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

As @John Rotenstein said; the limit is fixed since the introduction of SQS. What you may do is in your payload you put a field such as `expire_timestamp` (now + 1 hour). While processing your job, first you check whether the current time is greater than `expire_ timestamp`, if not then push back to SQS with 15 minutes. At fourth iteration you will process it.